# Could somebody explain how to pass globally the database variable in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

already tried a lot of tutorials, but somehow I could not figure it out.
I am using mongodb and express.js
this is in my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const routes = require('./routes');
const app = express();
var db;

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static('views'));
app.use(subdomain('api', routes.api));

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  db = database;
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000');
  });
});
```

and this is in my routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const api = express.Router();

api.get('/', function (req, res) {
  db.collection('test').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.render('api_orders', {test: result});
  });
});

module.exports = {
    api
}
```

I would like to use the db variable also in routes, but it always gives me the db is not defined error (obviously) I read that I should somehow export the db var, but could not managed to do it

Comment: use the `export` keyword.

Comment: should I export the db from app.js and require it in routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead i would suggest you to create another file and you just require it where you want to use it. Suppose:

#### db.js:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const db = function(){
    return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, database) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      return database;
    });
}

module.exports = db;
```

Now you can use the `db` anywhere when you do :

```
const mydb = require('./db'); // <--require it to use
```

<sub>*It may not work as it is not tested but it can give you idea to get through.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This is as much a question as a response. I've used

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, database)={
global.bigdb = database
});
```

and called it from the routes for instance

```
var col = global.bigdb.collection('collectionname');
```

Is this bad practice? Rereading the code - it's been live for a while - I'm also exposing the redis client as a global.

Any info appreciated. Live with no bug reports but very curious if I should refactor.

Comment: You pretty much want to avoid globals because it messes with modularity and invites conflicts between modules both trying to use the same global name.  This is one practice that occurs in browser Javascript code that node.js want to explicitly avoid in its architecture.  If you share variables with modules via import/export or via passing things to a module constructor, no globals are required and code will be more modular.

Comment: Thanks. Are there performance or security issues with exposing the database handles as globals?

Comment: Performance issues - I don't think so.  Security issues - that depends upon your environment.  Certainly you lose control of what code in your project can access the database by putting it where any code in the project can get to it.  Whether that is an issue or not depends upon your project.  It is generally NOT considered a best practice in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(function(req,res,next))
{
  res.locals.yourvariable = null; 
  next();
});
```

This is how I initialize global variables. Hope you get an idea.